# How to do texture mapping in openglES? ( Mapping 2D face into a 3D mesh )

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I need to convert a 2D face image to a 3D image. For this I thought of using texture mapping with openglES. I tried a lot googling to find some samples I couldnt get any. Can some one guide me to do this?

Input: 2D image
Output : 3D image

Platform : ios

Answer (score 2):

As you know, OpenGL is using 3D or 2D vertices that has a few attributes such as position, normal value, color, texture coordinate. So you should set these values first and you can render.
In ES 2.0 clearly you have to give these values to Vertice Shader 
and then you have to transfer two values texture coordinate , normal value to Fragment Shader 
and then in Fragment Shader, you can control these values with sampler texture for rendering your face object.

If you work In IOS, It's going to be very help .

Explanation :

http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596804824/chtextures.html

Source Code :

http://www.developers-life.com/iphone-3d-samples.html

Comment: Thanks for your links its really useful. But I need some examples on opengles on human face.

Comment: @2vision2 That's going to be completely same way but if you want to do texture mapping with some special algorithm like automatically calculate & create a face object depending on face texture that's going to be super hard. so I sugest using a 3D tool like Blender, 3D studio max or Maya.

Comment: @2vision2 Refer to this link http://cgcookie.com/blender/2010/10/13/update-projection-painting-in-2-5/